# Any way to programmatically install vmWare Player or VirtualBox or any other free virtualization package on a client computer together with an image?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-installation

I want to write an installer to automatically install some kind of virtualization software on clients running Windows, and download and start an image. Is it doable?

Comment: Sure.  Windows Installers support silent installations.  You can start VMWare and VirtualBox through a command line.

Comment: Are you looking for an automation solution? I am pretty sure things like Puppet can do this on windows.